# Save image from one database to another with php

Tags: php, mysql

Is possible select image from mysql (blob), put into input (text) and then save to another mysql (blob)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you saving a path or an actual file?

Comment: I save actual file...how do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  A binary string will preserve the data just fine.

EDIT: Here's an example

```
CREATE TABLE fooblob (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  data MEDIUMBLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

$dbh = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
# Read a blob
if(!$res = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM fooblob WHERE id = 1", $dbh)) {
    die("ERROR: " . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$data = $row['data'];

# Write it to a different row (pretend it's a different table)
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbh, "INSERT INTO fooblob(data) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $data);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is possible like this?

1.)

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
# Read a blob
if(!$res = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM fooblob WHERE id = 1", $dbh)) {
    die("ERROR: " . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$data = $row['data'];
```

2.)

```
<textarea name="test" id="test"><?= $data ?></textarea>
```

3.)

```
$post_data = $_POST['test'];   
$dbh = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
if(!$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fooblob (data) VALUES ('$post_data') WHERE id = 1", $dbh)) {
     die("ERROR: " . mysql_error());
}
```